# Joining based on dates

Tags: t-sql, join

I have two sets of data that I need to join.
However there is no ID or similar to join the sets, the only common factor between the two sets are the dates used.
Unfortunately the dates are not 100% identical, typically it’s a few minutes or seconds in difference between the two dates.
What I’m hoping is  that it would be possible to join based on the dates, if the difference between date for example is less than 10minutes.

Is this something that could be possible?

Example data:

```
> EventDate                 WindSpeed 
> 2018-01-09 12:00:18.000   3 
> 2018-01-10 12:00:03.000   4
```

Then join with:

```
> ReadingDate               ReadingValue
> 2018-01-09 12:00:00.000   4,6
> 2018-01-10 12:00:00.000   5
```

So far I have the two below queries that I’m not able to join by myself, would appreciate any help or hints to get this working:

```
SELECT tu.Name,
   tv.VoyageNo,
   tv.ExternalVoyageNo,
   tve.VoyageEventCode,
   tve.EventDate,
   tve.WindSpeed,
   tve.WindDirection,
   tve.SeaStateCode,
   tve.PositionLatitude,
   tve.PositionLongitude,
   tve.Speed,
   tve.DistanceByLog,
   tve.DistanceOverGround,
   tve.HFOStock,
   tve.LSFOStock,
   tve.MDOStock,
   tve.MGOStock,
   tve.DraughxcID,
   CASE
       WHEN ts.IsBallast = 0
       THEN 'Laden'
       WHEN ts.IsBallast = 1
       THEN 'Ballast'
       ELSE 'In Port'
   END AS Condition,
   tcf.Mt
FROM dbo.xcVoyageEvent tve
 INNER JOIN dbo.xcUnit tu ON tve.xcUnitID = tu.xcUnitID
 INNER JOIN dbo.xcVoyage tv ON tve.xcVoyageID = tv.xcVoyageID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.xcSailing ts ON tve.xcSailingID = ts.xcSailingID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.xcCargo tc ON tve.xcVoyageID = tc.xcVoyageID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.xcCargoFigure tcf ON tc.xcCargoID = tcf.xcCargoID
WHERE tve.RowDeleted = 0
  AND tv.RowDeleted = 0
  AND ts.RowDeleted = 0
  AND tu.RowDeleted = 0
  AND tve.VoyageEventCode IN('Commence Sea Passage', 'Sea Passage 
Suspended', 'Sea Passage Resumed', 'End Of Sea Passage', 'xcdailyreport', 
'Noon position', 'morning position', 'voyage commenced', 'voyage complete', 
'Enter Magallanes Strait', 'Enter Suez Canal', 'All Clear', 'All Fast')
 ORDER BY tu.Name,
     tve.EventDate;   

SELECT tu.name,
   tc.Code,
   tc.Name,
   xc.Name,
   xcr.ReadingValue,
   xcr.ReadingDate,
   xcr.Comment
FROM dbo.xcMeasurement xc
 INNER JOIN dbo.xcMeasurementReading xcr ON xc.xcMeasurementID = 
xcr.xcMeasurementID
 INNER JOIN dbo.xcComponent tc ON xc.xcComponentID = tc.xcComponentID
 INNER JOIN dbo.xcUnit tu ON xc.xcUnitID = tu.xcUnitID
WHERE xc.RowDeleted = 0
  AND xcr.RowDeleted = 0
  AND tu.RowDeleted = 0
  AND xc.Consumption = 1
ORDER BY tu.Name,
     tc.code,
     xcr.ReadingDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that there is a difference between the two dates in the different tables,

if it's just 1 "event" per day, you could join on either Date, or Datetime.

if you have multiple events per day, you'd also have to consider using Datediff in my example i used 600 seconds difference

See my example below

```
create table #temp1
( EventDate Datetime2, Windspeed int)

create table #temp2
( Readingdate Datetime2, Readingvalue nvarchar(50))

insert into #temp1 Values
('2018-01-09 12:00:18.000', 3),
('2018-01-09 13:10:00.000', 3),
('2018-01-10 12:00:03.000', 4)

insert into #temp2 Values
('2018-01-09 12:00:00.000', '5,6'),
('2018-01-09 13:00:00.000', '6'),
('2018-01-10 12:00:00.000', '5')


SELECT
    *,DATEDIFF(S,T2.Readingdate, T1.EventDate) [dif_in_sec]
FROM #temp1 AS T1
INNER JOIN #TEMP2 AS T2 ON  CAST(T1.EventDate AS date) = CAST(T2.Readingdate AS DATE) 
                            AND(     DATEDIFF(S,T2.Readingdate, T1.EventDate) <= 600 
                                 and DATEDIFF(S,T2.Readingdate, T1.EventDate) >= 0)
```

You might have to tweak with the values

Answer (score 2):

To get rows with EventDate and ReadingDate within 10 minutes add this to your where statement:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EventDate, ReadingDate)) <= 10
```